# Bash script for loop variable returns all files in directory rather than a single file name

Tags: linux, bash, valgrind

I'm looking to run valgrind on a series of files within a directory. The following bash script is able to pull in all the files I'm looking for, but the argument that is passed to valgrind is the entire list rather than a single file from the directory.

```
TESTDIR="/test/i386/bin"
APPDIR="./appdir"                     
for TEST in "$APPDIR$TESTDIR/TEST*"; do           
   valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full $TEST
done
```

Is there something I need modify with my for loop or the arguments I'm passing in to valgrind to retrieve a single item from the list?

Comment: Take the `*` out of the quotes.

Comment: `for TEST in "$APPDIR$TESTDIR/TEST"*; do`

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form; see relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, indicating that POSIX-defined tools use all-caps names for their own purposes, and leave lowercase names available for application use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That works! Thank you! Such a simple fix

Comment: In addition, for reliable results in case of strange file names, replace `valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full $TEST` with `valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full "$TEST"`